# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC: POSTing from jQuery all values are null in controller

Tags: jquery, .net, post, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm calling a controller endpoint from jQuery and the problem is all parameters are received as null by the endpoint.

`javascript`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Test/SendEmailWithCode',
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            mailTo: mailTo,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
            digit32: digit32,
            digit16: digit16,
            code: encrypt(generateCode(), digit32, digit16).toString()
        }),
    success: function (data) {
        $("#userCodeData").val("data");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    }
});
```

`Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendEmailWithCode(string mailTo, string subject, string message, string digit32, string digit16, string code)
{
    var result = _emailService.SendEmailWithCode(mailTo, subject, message);

    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Apparently everything's fine, but no way, the values are always null in the controller. What can I try next?

### Edit 1

The weird thing is that if I replace POST call by GET (type: "GET" in javascript + [HttpGet] in controller) values are received correctly, but that's not the case, I'm sending an email in controller, so the type of the call should be POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your ajax like below :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Test/SendEmailWithCode',
    type: "POST",
    data:{
            mailTo: mailTo,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
            digit32: digit32,
            digit16: digit16,
            code: encrypt(generateCode(), digit32, digit16).toString()
        },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#userCodeData").val("data");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    }
});
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Qing Guo, thanks for your reply. You are right, it's definitly working the way you've written, not specifying contentType and avoiding JSON.stringify. I thought contentType was mandatory in an ajax call, but it seems not. Maybe if you don't specify it picks up the most appropiate one?

Comment: Yes, you are reight.

Comment: I would add a description of what you have changed an why to the answer. Some times it's not obvious what has changed, for example the removal of the stringyfy wrapper is easily missed.